# Can't draw a line?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I want to draw a line as `ImageView's` background.But it doesn't work?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000FF" />
    <size android:width="10dp"
        android:height="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Just a demo.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dividing_line"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

Comment: Show us your layout xml!

Comment: @NikoYuwono you can see my layout demo

Comment: try to change width to 10dp instead of wrap_contentn

Comment: @Egos show output what you want to drow

Comment: @EgosZhang after that did you set an image to the ImageView?

Comment: I do nothing,just want to draw a line.setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` has no content so size will be 0x0dp. If you want a divider try setting the `width` to `match_parent` and the `height` to whatever you feel comfortable with (`2dp` for example).

*Update*: Try this.

In your layout file:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dividing_line"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

The drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#0000FF"/>
    <size android:height="2dp" />
</shape>
```

It is working for me.

---

As pointed out by [TheTool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035420/thetool) if you just want a divider the easier solution is to add

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="2dp" 
      android:background="@color/yourColor" />
```

to your layout file.

Comment: <ImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dividing_line"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" /> It doesn't work.

Comment: If this question is indeed about a divider, just add this to your xml: 
                    <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />